# Pass list of differently sized arrays to Numba function

Tags: numpy-ndarray, numba

I have a pre-computed list of differently sized arrays, and I'd like to pass it to a Numba function.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def go_fast(a, b): 
    ...
    return output

a = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
b=[np.arange(4),np.arange(9)]
```

(In reality, the elements of b are more complicated arrays, but this is just an example). How can I accomplish this? I know numba does not like lists.

One way would be to turn b into a high dimensional array with padding, but extracting the real elements would require loops, which isn't ideal. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like list of lists are supported in newer versions:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

Another option is typed lists and typed dicts:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#dict
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#list